# short way of ORing all flags

Tags: go, constants, logical-operators

With the following:

```golang
const (
    Flag1 = 0
    Flag2 = uint64(1) << iota
    Flag3      
    Flag4      
    Flag5      
)
```

is there a shorter/better way of doing, I want to OR them all:

```
const FlagAll = Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag3 | Flag4 | Flag5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your flags contain a single 1 bit, shifting the bit to the left, `FlagAll` would be the next in the line but subtract 1:

```
const (
    Flag1 = 0
    Flag2 = uint64(1) << iota
    Flag3
    Flag4
    Flag5
    FlagAll = uint64(1)<<iota - 1
)
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Printf("%08b\n", Flag1)
fmt.Printf("%08b\n", Flag2)
fmt.Printf("%08b\n", Flag3)
fmt.Printf("%08b\n", Flag4)
fmt.Printf("%08b\n", Flag5)
fmt.Printf("%08b\n", FlagAll)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/haZqOAIPU5k)):

```
00000000
00000010
00000100
00001000
00010000
00011111
```

Note that you get the same value if you left shift the last constant and subtract 1:

```
const FlagAll2 = Flag5<<1 - 1
```

But this requires to explicitly include the last constant (`Flag5`) while the first solution does not require it (you may add further flags like `Flag6`, `Flag7`..., and `FlagAll` will be right value without changing it).